# Sharepoint - page with "upload file" option?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, submit

I want to create a webpage with an option for a user to upload a file.
I do not want to create a document library, i just want a plain page with an option for the user to upload a file. The file should then be saved in a destination i set.

This is to allow users to submit files, but not let anyone see what have been uploaded. Think of it as a drop of of assignments for students that are sent to their teachers.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the Content Organizer feature (Site Features), which creates a "Drop Library" where your users can upload files. You can define rules depending on your requirements to route the documents to the desired destination library.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can make SharePoint 2013 add in (SharePoint hosted app). In app page put file upload and write logic, end user will not know where file submitted.

Comment: What do you mean? What app to use for this feature?